# How do I make enum that has value as an object?

Tags: typescript

If I change `StatusTypes` to be enum I get an error. I keep `StatusTypes` as an object so I can apply it consistently in my app like `StatusTypes.success`

```
export const StatusTypes = {
  idl: {name: 'idle', message: ''},
  success: {name: 'success', message: 'Success.'},
  error: {name: 'error', message: 'Something went wrong.'},
};

export type Status =
  | {name: 'idle'; message: ''}
  | {name: 'success'; message: 'Success.'}
  | {name: 'error'; message: 'Something went wrong.'};
```

How do I make `Status` type more concise without code duplication like above?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html and ctrl-f for "discriminated union"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better approach would be to make the `name` key to be an enum, then leave the message as a simple string (since the error message should be different for every different error)

Something like this:

```js
export type Status = {
  name: "idle" | "success" | "error"
  message: string
}

const StatusTypes: { idle: Status; success: Status; error: Status } = {
  idle: { name: "idle", message: "..." },
  success: { name: "success", message: "..." },
  error: { name: "error", message: "..." },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want some predefined status objects, how about something like this:

```ts
export class Status {
    static idle = new Status('idle', '');
    static success = new Status('success', 'Success.');
    static error = new Status('error', 'Something went wrong.');

    constructor(
        public readonly name: 'idle' | 'success' | 'error',
        public readonly message: string,
    ){}
}
```